# Empty Textbox values inside a GridView in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have this GridView and and on a button click want to send the whole gridview data in an email body (using SMTP)

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Heading 1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbxHeading1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Heading 2">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbxHeading2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Heading 3">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlHeading3" Height="26">
                <asp:ListItem Text="&nbsp;" Selected="True" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="list-1" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="list-2" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="list-3" />
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Heading 4">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbxHeading4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Heading 5">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbxHeading5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns></asp:GridView>

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"></asp:Button>
```

Button click:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder(); 
   StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter(strBuilder); 
   HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(strWriter); 
   GridView2.RenderControl(htw); 

   message.Body += strBuilder.ToString(); 
}
```

On button click I am getting the data in the email body but if the textbox value is empty I am getting an empty array. Like this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFZP5.png)

Is there anyway to hide the empty array "[   ]" if the textbox is empty?

**NOTE**: When I debug the code I am seeing no value attribute to the textbox. If I passed default value to texbox, no use.
Debug code:

```
<td><input name="defaultcontent_0$GridView2$ctl02$tbxHeading1" type="text" id="defaultcontent_0_GridView2_tbxHeading1_0" /></td>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace it with empty string before passing it to the message body like this

`strBuilder = strBuilder.replace("[]","");`

Comment: Thank you for your idea, but I already tried this - NO USE.